# span, extra-margin

Tags: css

Here is my html:

```
<div class="top_pane">
    <span class="button"><a href="/settings/">Settings</a></span>
    <span class="button"><a href="/export_all/">Export</a></span>
    <span class="button"><a href="/import/">Import</a></span>
</div>
```

and css:

```
span.button {
    float:right;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

div.top_pane {
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    background-color:#7D9100;
    height:45px;
    color:#FFFF9D;
}
```

I need additional space on the right side of all spans.

```
!         Import Export Settings <- i need extra space here -> !
```

I tried to create one more span:

```
<div class="top_pane">
    <span class="button"></span>
    <span class="button"><a href="/settings/">Settings</a></span>
    <span class="button"><a href="/export_all/">Export</a></span>
    <span class="button"><a href="/import/">Import</a></span>
    <span class="button"></span>
</div>
```

but it doesn't work.

What is the good way to add extra space on the right?

Comment: They are different questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/AMnMv/

(there's a red border on the div that gets space, simply add the class `giveMeSpace`)

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin-right` or `padding-right` to `.top_pane`

One reason you're not getting any extra margin with the empty spans is because they do not have any height, so the other elements are just slipping under them. If you give the spans a height then the original method would probably work. But its not the best idea as it is extra markup without any real value.

Comment: I have width:100%; on the parent container, and padding's doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add `padding-right: 200px` to the parent container.

Or if padding cannot be added to the parent container:

```
.top_pane:last-child {
    padding-right: 200px
}
```

Comment: I have width:100%; on the parent container, and padding's doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Spans won't push elements, what you could do is float three divs inside `#top_pane`

`<span class="button"><a href="/settings/">Settings</a></span>`
`<span class="button"><a href="/export_all/">Export</a></span>`
`<div class="button"><a href="/import/">Import</a></div>`

with css

`.button { float:left; }`
`div.button { margin-right:10px }`